# Select one of the radio buttons and click Submit which redirects other page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few radio buttons. On selecting either one and on Submit it will redirect to a specific page corresponding to the option.

I've googled quite a lot but can't seem to get rid of two problems.

- Select one radio button and on Submit redirects.
- Vertically align the buttons in the center of the page.

Here's the code -

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #333;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
form{display:inline;
}
.block{ 
position:absolute;
top:50%
}
.wrapper{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

HTML -

```
<body>
<h1 align="center">Menu</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp; </p>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="" >
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_0"/>Options112</label>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_1" />
Option2</label> 
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_2" style="display:inline-block"/>
Option3</label>
</div>
</form>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<br/>
  <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"  />
    <input type="submit" name="Contribute" id="Contribute" value="Contribute" />
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Limitation is to use javascript.

Comment: first you are not closing your div <div class="wrapper">

Comment: also change css for block class position:relative

Answer (score 1):

There is something weird on your html
your div tag is not closed properly as in by right normal div tag is `<div></div>`
but yours is apparently `<div </div>`

I have a solution for you, just need to copy and paste this into your current html and see the difference.

```
<div class="wrapper" >
  <input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_0"/>
    Option1
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_1"/>
    Option2
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_2"/>
Option3
</div>
```

Edited: I have updated the codes, that is due to the `text-align:center;`, what we can do is to shift it left by using margin or padding. in the updated version demo I used padding.  If you need a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2KQAy/3/) you go. Have a nice day

Comment: The issue is Option1 and Option2 are of same character length.
If I choose the name as of some different length it is no longer aligned.

Comment: Hey @R11G I have updated the jsfiddle, just check the demo again. Feel free to let me know again if there is any further issue. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Problem one:

Change the wrapper css declaration to this

```
.wrapper{
    width:150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

You can change the width and set the value you want...see the results in this [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/gJ6n8/9/)

Problem two:

What do you mean by redirect? You are posting both forms to the same page, not redirecting. If you want to post the values to a different page, then specify something in the "Action" attribute of the form tag. Also remove the spaces in the radio button's name attribute to make it cleaner

Hope it helps

Leo

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
<h1 align="center">Menu</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp; </p>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="" >
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_0"/>Option1</label>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_1" />
Option2</label> 
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio" id="RadioButtons_2" style="display:inline-block"/>
Option3</label>
</div>
</form>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<br/>
  <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"  />
    <input type="submit" name="Contribute" id="Contribute" value="Contribute" />
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

JQUERY--

this will submit your form

```
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhF6n/1/)

Comment: OP has mentioned : **Limitation is to use javascript.**